# In xquery, is there any difference between single and double quotes?

Tags: xquery

In xquery, is there any difference between single and double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For string literals, they work exactly like in JavaScript.

Spec: [XQuery 1.0, Section A.2.1: Terminal Symbols - StringLiteral](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#doc-xquery-StringLiteral):

```
StringLiteral ::= 
    ('"' (PredefinedEntityRef | CharRef | EscapeQuot | [^"&])* '"') | 
    ("'" (PredefinedEntityRef | CharRef | EscapeApos | [^'&])* "'")
```

Comment: Thank you. I have found the specs too, but I was not sure that there is not another semantic difference.